# Create dataframe from a input values

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am currently starting to create an app in Shiny library, the idea is that I save in a dataframe values that I entered manually (from in input), I created an app (simple), but when I try to save each value that I entered manually (in the input) the previous value is erased. The code I have now is very basic but the depends you can move on with my app. I want to do is that every value I enter through the input I will saved on a vector or if I have multiple inputs each vector is a column of a matrix. I appreciate you can help me:

```
ui.R:library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel( "", ""),
  sidebarPanel(wellPanel(
      textInput('datavalues', "Valor",""),
      actionButton("submit","Guardar")
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(   
    verbatimTextOutput('datatable')
  )
))
server.R: library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  data1= reactive({
    if(input$submit!=0){
      isolate({
        data.frame(paste(input$datavalues))
      })
    }
  })
  output$datatable<-renderPrint(function(){
    if(!is.null(data1())){
      d<-data1()
      print(d)
    }
  })
})
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly you have to understand how action button works.

   Action button (`input$submit` in you case) initial value is 0, but it increments by 1, every time you click, like a counter.
2. You can use this for adding values to  your vector or data

   ```
   # For vectors
   d[input$submit] <- input$datavalues
   # For Matrix
   d[input$submit, ] <- input$datavalues
   ```
3. Then display data frame 'd'